# How to delete a row in sql using vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

Sorry if its easy or basic i am brand new to sql and tables so im just trying to figure it out
Basically im trying to delete a row that the user selects
By having them click on a row then clicking a delete button but i don't know how that should look ive tried a few different ways but none of them seem to work.
No error comes up but it just dosen't delete the row

```
 Private Sub DeleteSelectedUsers()
    Dim connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection()
    connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=GERARD-PC\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=TestDB;User ID=AccountsUser;Password=password123"

    connection.Open()

    Dim adp As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter _
    ("Delete * from dgrdUsers.SelectedRows(0).Cells", connection)




End Sub
Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    Try

        Dim username As String = dgrdUsers.SelectedRows(0).Cells.Item("Username").Value.ToString()

        If (MessageBox.Show(Me, "Do you want to delete user " & username & "?", "Confirm Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = DialogResult.Yes) Then
            DeleteSelectedUsers()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Comment: First of all, you need to follow some basic SQL Tutorial. After a DELETE statement there is no * (except ms-access) then after the FROM you need the table name and a WHERE statement (unless you want to delete the WHOLE table). Finally, you can't expect the Sql parser to kwnow anything about what is a datagridview and interpret your string as a reference to the selected rows of your datagrid.

Comment: @Steve ok first off thank you and ive added the table name now in the from but i don't know what i would put in it ive tried putting (username = @username) in it but that dosent work even if i use (byVal username as string) as well it says (arguement not specified for parameter) I know you might not want to spoonfeed it to me but this is my first time trying to delete something in sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax required to delete a row in the database table requires at least three parts.

- The DELETE command
- The FROM statement to identify the table where the delete action should occur
- The WHERE condition to identify the record (or records) to delete

So it is a string like this: *DELETE FROM tablename WHERE condition*
and applied to your code you get this.

```
Private Sub DeleteSelectedUsers(userName as String)
    Using connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection()
       connection.ConnectionString = "...."
       connection.Open()
       Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand _
          ("DELETE FROM Table WHERE userName = @user", connection)
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = userName
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
   End Using
End Sub
```

*(Table and UserName are fantasy names because we don't know what is the actual schema of your database)*

Other things I have changed:

- The connection is created inside a using block to be sure a proper
  closure and dispose happens even in case of errors
- The name of the user to remove should be passed as parameter to the
  function
- No need to use an adapter when you just need to execute a single
  SqlCommand
- The query doesn't concatenate strings to build the command but use a
  parameter added to the command itself and specifying a type for the
  data matching the type on the database table